# Access: Trigger a macro when switching records

Tags: forms, ms-access

In my Access form, I have a macro that confirms that the form was filled out correctly. If the users click to another record, the macro should run, and if necessary, pop up a message box saying "Do you want to remain on this page?".  If "no", it proceeds to the next record, and if "yes", it stays on the same record. Either way, any changes the user had made are retained.

I'm not sure which Form Event that I should tie this macro to, and whether it should use CancelEvent to stay on the same record.

AfterUpdate seems to be closest, but the CancelEvent keeps it on the same record whether I press Yes or No.

(It's okay if the macro runs - or doesn't run - when the user hasn't changed anything, such as when scanning through the records. Whichever is easier.)

PS: I'd like to keep using this macro, but if I have to use VBA I'll probably use this solution: [Run VBA on record change and not form open Access 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616840/run-vba-on-record-change-and-not-form-open-access-2013)

Comment: AfterUpdate does not have Cancel. Use BeforeUpdate event to validate record data. VBA or macro. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713337/require-that-form-fields-are-filled-before-saving-a-record

Comment: CancelEvent is a macro command. Are you saying that it cannot cancel the AfterUpdate event?

Comment: Suppose I use BeforeUpdate. How do I have the record updated whether the user chooses Yes or No? And how to have the current record *remain* the current one if Yes is chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how you can use the forms `BeforeUpdate` event with VBA (see comments in code):

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    'If no pending edits were made in the current record,
    'let the user move to another record.
    If Not Me.Dirty Then Exit Sub

    'You can check the user entries here, and if all is fine
    'just exit the sub, so the user can move to another record
    '(pending edits will be saved automatically).
    'This is just an example:
    If Me.Field1 = "a" And Me.Field2 = "b" Then Exit Sub

    'If the user doesn't want to stay on the current record,
    'let him move to another record (pending edits will be saved automatically).
    If MsgBox("Do you want to remain on this page?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
        "Attention") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    'Cancel moving to another record.
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

`Me` in VBA used in the forms code points to the current form instance.

Comment: If the processing goes all the way through to Cancel, will the changes the user made be undone or saved?

Comment: The state then is the same as if the user wouldn't have tried to move to another record: Any pending edits are still present and unsaved. The user then can/has to save the edits or undo them.

Comment: I was really looking for a macro (non-VBA) solution because I had the macro already written, but you made me realize where I had mis-coded my macro. Now it works in the BeforeUpdate event. So thanks!